# How to avoid text-decoration line-through affecting all rows

Tags: jquery, html-table, document-body

I have an asp:GridView rendering html as follows:

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="4" rules="all" id="MainContent_gvTODOList" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="MainContent_gvTODOList_chkTaskComplete_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$gvTODOList$ctl02$chkTaskComplete" 
            onclick="TaskCompleteCheckChanged(this);" />
        </td>
        <td>asdfs</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$gvTODOList&#39;,&#39;Delete$0&#39;)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="MainContent_gvTODOList_chkTaskComplete_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$gvTODOList$ctl03$chkTaskComplete" 
            onclick="TaskCompleteCheckChanged(this);" />
        </td>
        <td>bxbbbbww www</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$gvTODOList&#39;,&#39;Delete$1&#39;)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="MainContent_gvTODOList_chkTaskComplete_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$gvTODOList$ctl04$chkTaskComplete" 
            onclick="TaskCompleteCheckChanged(this);" />
        </td>
        <td>nhh ssw</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$gvTODOList&#39;,&#39;Delete$2&#39;)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My jQuery function is as follows:

```
function TaskCompleteCheckChanged(chkBox) {
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {               
            $("tbody").find("tr").each(function () { //get all rows in table
                var tdTaskDesc = $(this).find('td:eq(1)');

                if (chkBox.checked)
                {
                    if (tdTaskDesc.prevObject[0].innerText.length > 0) {                          
                        // $(this).addClass('strikeout');
                        $(tdTaskDesc).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tdTaskDesc.prevObject[0].innerText.length > 0) {
                        // $(this).removeClass('strikeout');
                        $(tdTaskDesc).css('text-decoration', 'none');
                    }                      
                }                                                              
            });                       
        });
    }
```

I am trying to cause the text in the second column of the table to show the strike-through effect when I check the checkbox in the first column.
Unfortunately all rows display the strike-through, despite trying to follow this link and others: https://codepen.io/nericksx/pen/CKjbe

I only want the current rows where the checkbox is checked to display the strike-through on the second td in the tr element, aka the text description.

Comment: Can you update your codepen to better simulate your code? There aren't any check boxes to check and you haven't even written and js there.

Comment: It isn't my codepen !!!! I was trying to find the answer to my problem.  Also, here is my CSS  td {
    /* padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0; */
    position: relative;
}

tr.strikeout td:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 2%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
    width: 100%;
}

tr.strikeout td:after{
    content: "\00B7";
    font-size: 1px;
}

Comment: Had some success:  Changed my jQuery to this:  function TaskCompleteCheckChanged(chkBox)
        {
            var description = $('tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').find('td');

            if (chkBox.checked)
                $(description).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
            else
                $(description).css('text-decoration', 'none');
        }

Comment: I should have done this using Angular 2 - would have been soooo easy!